# NameValueCollection.Get() alternative for DataRow

Tags: c#, datarow, datacolumn

I can safely get a value from a `NameValueCollection` using `NameValueCollection.Get()`, if the key doesn't not exist then a null is returned.

However many times I want to try to load a `DataColumn` value, unfortunately `dr["BadColumn"]`
will throw an exception.

Is there a simpler way than having to create a checking method?

Comment: You want to access a `DataRow` but you doesn't know it's columns? You can use [`dr.Table.Columns.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx) to check it(or `dr.Table.Columns` to loop all available columns).

Comment: that's basically what I have been doing in an extension method. just thought there might be an inbuilt way

Answer (score 0):

Go with the suggestion of @Tim Schmelter . You might perform that check in an extension method for DataRow if you would like and also give that an alternative default for scenarios where you would like some other value rather than null.

```
public static Object GetOrDefault(this DataRow dr, String columnName, String defaultValue = null)
{
    if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName)) return dr[columnName];
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: You could make it generic like `DataRow.Field` ;-)